# Can I ignore events from specific mixpanel-profiles?

Tags: mixpanel

I found this article: https://mixpanel.com/help/questions/articles/can-i-exclude-myself-from-mixpanel-data

Mixpanel suggests that the users that should be ignored paste this into the webclient:

```
mixpanel.register({"$ignore":true});
```

I have two problems with this:

1: I'm building an app, not a webpage, so I don't have a dev-console.
2: I am not in control of all the accounts that I want to ignore.

Is there some way to perform this operation on a profile from the admin-interface of mixpanel? According to their documentation, this will create a superproperty.

Comment: {"$Ignore":true} basically adds a property to the people data, based on which we can filter the results. If this is the purpose of the above question, then you can do this directly from the people dashboard of mixpanel.

Comment: As per the same article you have attached:-

"If you would like to be able to filter out internal user profiles, you can add a People Property to each internal user's profile (e.g. Internal User: True) either manually via Explore or programmatically upon login".

Comment: This is nice, but as far as I can understand you can't apply a filter to for example the retention report.

Comment: You can apply that if you are looking at Event based retention report. There you will get an option to filter based on People properties.

Comment: Ah, you need to set an event for this to work, ok, thx!